# How to perform multithreading operations on random positions in the same array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, random, parallel-processing

I have a process running lots of tasks on random positions in `Array` and would like to speed this up by the use of multithreading.

What it essentially does is to randomize a position in "Array", check its close surroundings for its values and alter the random position values if a few specific conditions are met.

Would it be possible to run something like a

```
Parallel.For(0, n, s => { });
```

loop instead of the while chunk of code shown below to optimize this function, and how would a block of code to do this look like?

I've been thinking about using some "busy" property for the chosen elements but that essentially makes the problem more complicated that it might need to be.

```
public void doStuffTothisArray(ref int[,,] Array, ref IGenerator randomGenerator, int loops)
{
    int cc = 0;
    int sw = 0;
    do
    {
        if (doStuffOnRandomPositions(ref Array, ref randomGenerator))
            sw++; //if stuff was made counter

        if ((cc % (loops / 10)) == 0)
            Console.Write("{0} % \t", (cc / (loops / 10)) * 10); //some loading info

        cc++; //count iterations
    } while (cc < loops);
    Console.WriteLine("Stuff altered in {0} iterations: {1}", loops, sw);
}
```

**Post edit:**

Dividing the array and distributing the work destroys the dynamics of the array, since it needs to be a complete system.

Here's a prototype of the dostuff..()

```
public static bool doStuffOnRandomPositions(ref lattice A, ref IGenerator rr)
{
    position firstPos = new position(rr.Next(0, A.n_size),rr.Next(0, A.n_size),rr.Next(0, A.n_size));
    position secondPos = randomNeighbour(ref A, firstPos, ref rr);

    //checks the closest 3d neighbours indexer the lattice
    //Console.WriteLine("first:[{0},{1},{2}]\nsecond:[{3},{4},{5}]\n", firstPos.x, firstPos.y, firstPos.z, secondPos.x, secondPos.y, secondPos.z);

    //  get values at coordinates
    bool first = A.latticeArray[firstPos.x, firstPos.y, firstPos.z];
    bool second = A.latticeArray[secondPos.x,secondPos.y,secondPos.z];

    if (first == second) //don't bother if they are equal states
        return false;

    //  checks the energies in surroundings for an eventual spin switch
    int surrBefore = surroundCheck(ref A, firstPos, first) ; // - surroundCheck(ref A, secondPos, second));
    int surrAfter = surroundCheck(ref A, firstPos, !first) ; // - surroundCheck(ref A, secondPos, !second));

    if (surrAfter < surrBefore) //switch spin states if lower total energy
    {
        A.latticeArray[firstPos.x, firstPos.y, firstPos.z] = !first;
        A.latticeArray[secondPos.x, secondPos.y, secondPos.z] = !second;
        return true;
    }
    else if ((surrAfter == surrBefore) & latticeDistribution(ref rr))   //TEMPORARY
    {
        A.latticeArray[firstPos.x, firstPos.y, firstPos.z] = !first;        //TEMPORARY
        A.latticeArray[secondPos.x, secondPos.y, secondPos.z] = !second;    //TEMPORARY
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
} //FIX SWITCH PROBABILITIES
```

In this, the lattice class is supposed to represent the "array" with its properties incorporated. Example solution code would be very thanksful due to my inxperience with the c# methods.

Comment: Given that you're mutating the array, which is shared state, I can't see how this can possibly be optimized without riddling it with race conditions.

Comment: are the indices of possible modifications deterministic based on the selected index provided by the RNG?  If so, you could build in synchronization to prevent parallelism when possible modifications could overlap.  This would only make sense if `doStuffOnRandomPositions` is complex enough to warrant the additional overhead of parallelism and synchronization

Comment: To avoid race conditions you _could_ have array of lock objects (or similar synchronization) per item. This will depend on the determinism of the objects that @Moho mentioned, as well as the complexity of your method. Locking on these multiple objects could also create deadlocks. You will have to design the locking mechanism to avoid this.

Comment: show the code for `doStuffOnRandomPositions`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your operations are scoped to non-intersecting ranges of elements (like 1-10, 25-40, 100-123) that you can instead of running in parallel for individual elements run operations on separate ranges. If you don't re-allocate array while operations are in progress you will not need any other synchronization.

If you operations change random elements you'd have to work on proper synchronization and may not be able to get any benefits of running code on multiple threads.